# How to zip a byte array using ZipFileSystem

Tags: java, arrays, zip

How to create a zip file with a byte array using `ZipFileSystem` ?

The example in the [Zip File System Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html) shows how to zip an existing one, but I don't seem to find a way to create one from in memory byte array.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize I was using the same value for the target zip file and the file **inside** the zip file.

Modifying the original example I have this working:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class ZipFSPUser {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Throwable {
        Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
        env.put("create", "true");
        // locate file system by using the syntax
        // defined in java.net.JarURLConnection
        URI uri = URI.create("jar:file:/codeSamples/zipfs/zipfstest.zip");

        try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {
            Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath("/SomeTextFile.txt");
            // copy a file into the zip file
            Files.write(pathInZipfile, new byte[]{'h', 'i'} );

        }
    }
}
```

Now the `/codeSamples/zipfs/zipfstest.zip` file is created with `/SomeTextFile.txt` inside and when I unzip it the content is indeed `hi`